# how to move bootstrap cards to center with space between them

Tags: html, css, django-templates, frontend, web-frontend

I have multiple 5 cards displayed on my website as give in the image link below i need them to be move to center with space between them the shape of  them should be in squares..

[image: This is how it looks now] i want it be as below

[image: This is the way i need]

html template

```
<div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
 <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">s</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">s</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">s</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">s</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">s</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Are you use bootstrap? tell framework ver..

Comment: Yes bro i am using bootstrap

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>